# Byte Math Calculation

Tags: math, byte

Let's say we have a setting byte that equals and you know that b1-b4 are always 1 or 0

`b1 + b2*2 + b3*8 + b4*16`

You receive a value doesn't matter what value, let's just say 25,

How would you figure out what bytes are set?

Comment: Try something simpler first: can you figure out the value of `b4`?

Comment: No, not really,  we know it is 1 or 0, same as all others.

Comment: If the value is, say, 25, could `b4` be 0? Try playing with the other bits and see if you can make 25 without `b4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit can be either 0 or 1. Start from the biggest number (16) and subtract from the target decimal number if target is bigger than or equal to it. Otherwise do nothing and set that bit to 0.

For example, for 25: 
is 16 <= 25? : Yes, therefore b4 = 1  Subtract 16 from 25. 
is 8 <= (25-16) : Yes, therefore b3 = 1  Subtract 8 from 9. 
is 2 <= (25-16-8) : No, therefore b2 = 0 
is 1 <= (25-16-8) : Yes, therefore b1 = 1  Subtract 1 from 1.

So it is:  1101 (b4 b3 b2 b1)
It is exactly the same logic applied when making transformation from decimal numbers to binary numbers. However, b3 is multiplied with 8, not 4 in your question (why though?)

What is the logic behind this?
Well, when there is N in your number (like 16 in 25), we know that all other numbers below N, ( N/2  N/4  N/8  etc.) cannot be summed up to N. Their sum will be N - 1. You can find it with an easy calculation: [calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/289dO.png)